# Ajax .done(function(feedback) not taking into account the "feedback" part

Tags: php, ajax

i'm making a php form that I insert into a mysql table using ajax. And I have an issue, obviously.

Here is my JS, the only thing that doesn't work is the done function which never takes into account the "msg" part, it always displays "failed".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit-button').click(function(){
    var data = $('#myform').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "my-file.php",
        data: data
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        console.log(msg);
        if(msg == "create"){
            $('.message').fadeIn().html('created row').delay(1600).fadeOut();
        } else if(msg == "maj"){
            $('.message').fadeIn().html('updated row').delay(1600).fadeOut();
        } else {
            $('.message').fadeIn().html('failed').delay(1600).fadeOut();
        }
    });
});});
```

Here is the part of my-file.php in which I echo either 'create' or 'maj' depending on the action made.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
if($count == 0){
$sql = "INSERT INTO testCookie (
  `option_cms_name`,
  `option_cms_value`, 
  `option_cms_type`,
  `option_cms_version`,
  `option_cms_libelle`,
  `option_cms_description`,
  `option_cms_lien`,
  `option_cms_active`,
  `option_cms_date_crea`,
  `option_cms_modif`,
  `option_cms_users_id`
  )
  VALUES 
  ('cookies', '".$cookievarstock."','script' ,'1.0' ,'Cookies' ,'Barre dinformation sur les cookies' ,'' ,'1' ,'2015-12-08 14:14:00' ,'".$cookiedate."' ,1);";
    echo 'create';
}
else{
$sql = "UPDATE testCookie SET option_cms_value='".$cookievarstock."' WHERE option_cms_name='cookies';";
  echo 'maj';
}
}
```

I don't know what's the issue as when I check in the console, either 'maj' or 'create' shows up...

I'll be really grateful if any of you has some idea on why it doesn't work. Thanks!

EDIT : Here is what my $count variable does, just checking if the row already exists.

```
 $checkcookie = "SELECT option_cms_name FROM testCookie WHERE option_cms_name='cookies'"; 
$proccesscookie = $conn->query($checkcookie);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($proccesscookie);
```

EDIT 2 : I just found the issue and it's quite stupid, I just had two empty lines at the end of my php file. I checked the number of displayed characters with

```
var numbmsg = msg.length;
alert(numbmsg);
```

and it displayed 5 while it should have been 3 -> these two empty lines at the end of my php.
THANKS! =)

Comment: set dataType: 'text' in your ajax request object

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the php code like this:

**Note:** I don't know what you meant by variable **$count**.

```
$msg = 'post is empty';
if (!empty($_POST)) { 
if($count == 0){
$sql = "INSERT INTO testCookie (
  `option_cms_name`,
  `option_cms_value`, 
  `option_cms_type`,
  `option_cms_version`,
  `option_cms_libelle`,
  `option_cms_description`,
  `option_cms_lien`,
  `option_cms_active`,
  `option_cms_date_crea`,
  `option_cms_modif`,
  `option_cms_users_id`
  )
  VALUES 
  ('cookies', '".$cookievarstock."','script' ,'1.0' ,'Cookies' ,'Barre dinformation sur les cookies' ,'' ,'1' ,'2015-12-08 14:14:00' ,'".$cookiedate."' ,1);";
    $msg = 'create';
}
else{
$sql = "UPDATE testCookie SET option_cms_value='".$cookievarstock."' WHERE option_cms_name='cookies';";
  $msg = 'maj';
}
}
echo $msg;
```

Comment: This still doesn't work, and well, I don't really get why it should work better either. I'm far from being a good developper so I wouldn't know anyway... I have the feeling the issue comes from something in the JS as 'create' or 'maj' are displaying properly. I just tried to put "alert(msg);" in my done function and it displays 'maj'...

Comment: The only reason my <div class="message"> actually shows up (displaying failed) is that it's only requiry is for "created" and "updated" not to show up. If I add an initial 'value' to $msg in my php and add "else if(msg == 'value'){}" instead of "else{}" in my JS -> Nothing shows up and my console still says 'maj'.